# Should response text be set in the backend or front?

Tags: php, json, ajax, rest, codeigniter

I'm building a site that uses quite a lot of AJAX requests to sign in, update information and add content.

I am currently using CodeIgnitor for the project and wondering whether a response of either success

```
"Success, you have updated your profile"
```

or error

```
"There was an error updating your profile!"
```

should have a message that is set in the JS function or if it should simply be put in the JSON response but unsure which is better for future development. What do you suggest?

The message is to be used in a toast/message notification on the page on request callback.

My original idea was to have a basic key value array somewhere in the project like so:

```
array(
    100 => "Cannot update profile",
    101 => "Successfully updated profile",
    102 => "Cannot authenticate user",
    103 => "Successfully authenticated!",
    104 => "Unable to load profile data"
)
```

But thought this might get confusing and sluggish over time.

Comment: dont overthink. just choose one and see if it works for you. thats how you grow in programming.

Comment: If it is only one or two messages then it might be better off letting the front-end to create the message. If handling multiple messages then having a central back-end variable, or what ever, would make maintenance a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it really depends on your application and the technologies you are using.

In most cases I would go with the JSON response. Keep in mind that in the near future you will have to worry about translations, you may need to catch different exceptions for the user registration etc.

I think it is better to handle this logic and have messages in backend.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need more security for your web application you need to verify all request on the server side, that means send your data with ajax and verify all of this on the server side with CodeIgniter and return success or error message from server side with status code of HTTP protocol for example (201 : success , 422 : Unprocessable entity ..) and more another status you can find it, just google it if you are curious

Answer (score 0):

Why not return a response variable from your CodeIgnitor script and then use this in your front-end AJAX function to show errors:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response == 100) 
        <p> Cannot update profile </p>
    else if (response == 101) 
        <p> Successfully updated profile </p>
    else if (response == 102) 
        <p> Cannot authenticate user </p>
    ...
    ...
    ...
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to send your either success or error message from backend,
This is good for

- It can help you in Translation feature for the future
- modifying those message can be easily.
- The messages can be customizable to end user.
- Look professional (non-generic msg)
- Can have lower code on the frontend (AJAX).
- Can help you what each response does on backend to client.